# Def. about neighborhood on wiki

Tags: general-topology

The def on wiki:
"If $X$ is a topological space and $p$ is a point in $X$, a neighbourhood of $p$ is a subset $V \subseteq X$ that includes an open set $U$ containing $p$."

And it says: "Note that the neighbourhood $V$ need **not** **be an open** set itself."

Later, it says: "A set that is a neighbourhood of each of its points **is** **open**."

The claims above seem odd; one says a neighborhood need not be open; the other, be open.
I know the difference is one says a point; the other, a set. Is there any other 
strict explanation?

Thanks

Comment: The second sentence does not say that a neighbourhood of any point is open. It says that if it is a neighbourhood *of each of its points*, then it is open. Not every neighbourhood of some point has this property.

Comment: consider, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the closed disk of radius 1 about the origin. This is a neighborhood of the point $(0,0)$, since it contains the open disk of radius 1 about the point $(0,0)$. However, this is not a neighborhood for the point $(1,0)$ since there is no open set about the point $(1,0)$! Therefore, the closed disk is not open. Good. haha

Comment: @chen No. The second says that a neighbourhood is only open if it is a neighbourhood of each of its points. For example, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $V=[0,1]$. Then $V$ is a neighbourhood of each of the points in $(0,1)$, but it is not a neighbourhood of 0 (or 1).

Comment: @almagest. I am confused about your answer for the following: [0,1],which is the neighborhood of each of points in (0,1) is closed, not open. However, before it, you say a neighbourhood is only open if it is a neighbourhood of each of its points.

Comment: Which half of it: that $V$ is a nei of 1/2, or that it is not a nei of 0?

Comment: I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The statement you have doesn't contradict the fact that a neighborhood **need not be open**, it just happens to be open, given the added condition that it is a neighborhood to each of its points:

Let $V$ be a neighborhood of some point $p$. Suppose $V$ is a neighborhood for each of its points, that means if $x \in V$, then there exists $U$ open with $x \in U \subseteq V$. Conclude that $V$ is open by definition of open set.